# Why differences in below two method invocation where we have same generic list as the method parameter?

Tags: java, generics

*CASE 01:*

```
public static  void processNumber(List<Number> nums){

}
```

If the method is invoked as below, compiler gives error.

```
processNumber(new ArrayList<Float>());
```

*CASE 02 :*

But on the contrary if we have below method. Here `<Number>` is specified as type parameter

```
public static <Number> void processNumber(List<Number> nums){
              ^^^^^^^^ 
}
```

then the below invocation not giving any error...

```
processNumber(new ArrayList<Float>());
```

Why is that so?In one case it is giving error and in another, no error..why?

Comment: The signature in case 2 is equal to using `List<T>`, where `T` is an unbounded type parameter. The `Number` type parameter is just hiding the `java.lang.Number` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can see that the **method parameter turns into Ljava/util/List** as shown **in the byte code** by the compiler.See the highlighted portion in the image.

This is because we have unbounded Type Parameter in method.Hence it replaces it with Object once it is compiled.

**More Detail:**
To implement generics, the Java compiler applies type erasure.Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded.The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.

Hence this is just the generic List as the method parameter and can accept List of any Object. not just the List of Number and its subclasses..All below invocation are correct one.

```
processNumber(new ArrayList<Float>());
processNumber(new ArrayList()); //raw type
processNumber(new ArrayList<String>()); //String is not subclass of Number
processNumber(new ArrayList<SampleClass1>()); //user defined class
processNumber(new ArrayList<SampleClass2>()); //user defined class
```

[image: We can see that the signature turns into java/util/List as shown in the byte code by compiler, See Highlighted portion]

Answer (score 3):

```
public static <Number> void processNumber(List<Number> nums){

}
```

is a generic method with an unbounded type parameter. It's the same as:

```
public static <T> void processNumber(List<T> nums){

}
```

hence when you call `processNumber(new ArrayList<Float>());` the type `Float` is inferred by the compiler (you can also pass an `ArrayList<String>` for example). You just choose a bad name for the generic type parameter which maybe confused you.

On the other hand

```
public static  void processNumber(List<Number> nums){

}
```

is a method that accepts a `List<Number>` (the `Number` class) as parameter. As a [`List<Float>` is not a subclass of `List<Number>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p), you get a compile error.

Comment: thanks for the reply...you told that "List<Float> is not a subclass of List<Number>"
 I agree with that.But why the same rule is not true in case 2?
 
 Are you telling that 
 List<Float> is not a subclass of List<Number> in case1.
 But List<Float> is a subclass of List<Number> in case2 and it is because of generic method.

Comment: @027 No in the case 2, you have a generic method with an unbounded type parameter, hence you can pass whatever list you want (a `List<String>`, `List<Integer>`, `List<Character>`, ...)

Comment: @Alexis C, Again thanks ,But can i verify that from any way like, i can see/confirm that things(unbounded type) are replaced by Object in byte code or any other way which can give me some clue that it is generic method in case2, please give your comment if you have any idea. It would be helpful to clear my core understanding about the matter?

Comment: @027 I don't understand what you don't get exactly. But the method signature in the case 2 corresponds to how you declare a generic method (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html and the JLS https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4 with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4).

Answer (score 1):

In the 2nd Code snippet 
  `static <Number> void processNumber(List<Number> nums){`

Number is just a type variable its not the Class java.lang.Number

Hence the above code is equal to

```
static <T> void processNumber(List<T> nums){
```

Where T is type variable